# Remove text from brackets if certain word exist inside brackets in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a sample string

```
s='((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (vbc vb XyZ vc))'
s = '((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (XyZ vc))'
s = '((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (vc XyZ))'
```

if XyZ appear anywhere inside the brackets starting , ending then remove text within that parenthesis

```
output  ='((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)))'
```

How could I do it in the easiest possible way in Python? Maybe by using RegEx (which I am not good at)?

Comment: Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
re.sub(r"\s*\((\w|\s)*(xyz|XyZ)(\w|\s)*\)", "", s)
```

Result

```
'((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)))'
```

The regex `\s*\((\w|\s)*(xyz|XyZ)(\w|\s)*\)` is getting any whitespace character followed by ( followed by any whitespace character zero or more or word character zero or more than the XyZ pattern and again any whitespace character zero or more or word character zero or more followed by )

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this logic is not  working when sentence 'xyz' appears starting & ending of the sentence. like s='((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (vbc vb XyZ ))', s='((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (XyZ vb XyZ vc ))' . in this kind of scenarios. also my fault i didn't mentioned all this in the description

Comment: I don't understand both of the strings s='((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (vbc vb XyZ ))', s='((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (XyZ vb XyZ vc ))' are returning '((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)))'

Comment: sorry, what i mean is xyz can appear at any place inside the closed brackets ex :   1)    s='((Xyz_lk) (XYZ_l)) (vbc vb XyZ))' , 2)   s='((Xyz_lk) (XYZ_l)) (xyz vb))'. like starting ,ending, middle anywhere.  out put  should be =  ((Xyz_lk) (XYZ_l))).

Comment: Check the edited regex it's should get these cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this.

> 1> Check weather the required string (XyZ) is in given string.
>
> 2> After getting the location find the location of the parenthesis
>   surrounding that string.
>
> 3> Skip that part of string in output string.

```
s='((Xyz_lk) some stuff (XYZ_l)) (vbc vb XyZ vc))'

if "XyZ" in s:
    index = s.index("XyZ")

i = j = index   

while s[i] != "(":
    i -= 1

while s[j] != ")":
    j += 1

output = (s[ :i] + s[j+1:])
print(output)
```